# Пакеты склеиваются

Tags: c#, java, сеть

```
public class NetCon extends Thread {

    String address = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 3458;

    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;

    public ArrayList<String> queue;

    public Boolean Connect()
    {
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
            Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);

            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

            in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            queue = new ArrayList<String>();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void SendText(String s) {
        try {
            out.write(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.flush();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
            //System.out.println(queue.get(i)); //если убрать коммент. то ок
            SendText(queue.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

В queue находится две строки "test1", "test2". Запускаю поток, идёт отправка на сервер. Проблема в том, что иногда получаю 2 пакета как и положено, первый пакет со строкой "test1", второй с "test2", а иногда проскакивает что получаю пакет "test1test2". Если перед отправкой на сервер выводить на экран, то получается маленькая задержка и работает тогда всегда правильно. Почему между пакетами нужна эта пауза? Как сделать нормально?

Вот фрагмент кода сервера C# (TcpClient)

```
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int count;
while ((count = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, count));
   Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, count));
   ns.Flush();
}
```

Comment: @asterl, тут уже есть два ответа, в которых тщательно обсасываются **логические пакеты** прикладного протокола.

--

Для понимания сути проблемы хочу заострить внимание на том, что **в TCP НЕТ ПАКЕТОВ!!!**. С т.з. *прикладной* программы TCP сокет это *два* ***потока*** *байт*.

Вот из этого и следует исходить, проектируя обмен данными по TCP.

--

Поскольку речь идет о C# и Java я не буду углубляться в связанную с системными вызовами возможное (и в ряде случаев предсказуемое) деление потока на порции.

Comment: Комментарий хороший и правильный, только Вы не учли малый практический опыт автора вопроса, и оперируете слишком абстрактными понятиями. Я не думаю, что от объяснения настолько тонкой сути как-либо поможет автору. По себе могу сказать, что быстрее понять суть технологии сетевой передачи мне помогло то, что при изучении я оперировал именно понятиями пакетов, а не потоков.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов, возможно Вы правы и тичер из меня никудышний.

В том, что в основе большинства используемых сетевых технологий лежит коммутация пакетов, Вы безусловно правы. 

Кстати, об OOB Вы помните?

--

Помогает ли это знание (или наоборот) в написании правильных программ на TCP сокетах - не знаю. По крайней мере на ХэшКоде полно вопросов, подобных этому (т.е. автор неявно подразумевает, что сколько байт он отправил одним send-ом/write-ом - столько он  и получит *за один* recv/read). 

Конечно, вполне возможно, что правильных программ намного больше (только их авторы нам тут неизвестны)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Скорость сокета - непредсказуемая штука.
Бывает, что пакет пришел ещё не весь, а программа уже читает буфер - пакет получен не весь, а следующий искажен.
Бывает, что программа не дернула буфер сокета вовремя, и пришел ещё один или больше пакетов. Программа дергает буфер - и получает склеившиеся пакеты.

Всё дело в устройстве TCP/IP, и вытекающем из него устройстве сокета и его буфера. Сетевые пакеты ни как не обозначают свою длину, если програмист не позаботился об этом. В сокет приходит байт, и он сразу помещается в конец своего буфера. Не имеет значения, пришел один байт или миллион. Когда программа вызывает метод чтения, если не указана читаемая длина - возвращается весь буфер в обратном порядке, а если указана - то байты от нулевого до указанного в обратном порядке. Таким образом программист сам обязан обозначивать размер или диапазон байтов в пакете.

Решений несколько. От самых неправильных к наиболее подходящему:

1) Фиксировать размер пакета. Встречал несколько раз в чужом коде. Наличествует ещё и свой буфер, в который до нужного заполнения сливают данные буфера сокета, и читают нужными порциями. Стоит ли говорить, что вещь ужасно хардкодная?

2) В пакете означают его конец, к примеру каким-нибудь сочетанием 00-FF-00-FF. Встречал 2 раза. Велосипедизм. Возможны ложные срабатывания детектора конца пакета.

3) Первыми двумя (или четырьмя, если пакет планируется длинным) байтам обозначают либо размер всего пакета, либо размер "полезной части. Программа в цикле ждет 2 байта в буфере сокета, и читает их. Далее программа ждет появления N байтов или больше в сокете, где N - цифра, прочтенная из первых двух байтов. Далее программа читает N байт в свой буфер, и обрабатывает их. Цикл входит в новую итерацию.

Помогать конкретным кодом не стану, если автор не попросит этого прямо. Я пропагандирую самостоятельное развитие ума с возможными подсказками.

**Добавлено:**

Вспомнил, что встречал ещё одну разновидность велосипедизма, похожую на ответ ниже.
В первых 4 байтах передавался идентификатор пакета (обычный int), он передавался в обработчик пакетов, где свитчем выбирался нужный, создавался экземпляр этого пакета, в конструкторе читалось нужное количество байтов, и пакет обрабатывался. Самое смешное, что такой велосипед присутствует в одном, довольно известном и, пожалуй, знаменитом, приложении. Сообщить название продукта и производителя не могу по причине NDA.

В принципе, такой метод вполне жизнеспособен, и, возможно, полностью пропитан духом ООП, но мне он кажется через чур странным... Ведь одио из основных негласных принципов ООП является отсутствие хардкода, а в таком решении размер пакета захардкожен.

Comment: PS: Я пару лет назад натолкнулся на ту же проблему, пришлось изучать всё досконально... Теперь я смело могу защитить диссертацию на эту тему, не готовясь. :)

Comment: PPS: Исходя из лучшего построения взаимодействия, использовать лучше не строку, а массив байтов(byte[]) или лист байтов (ArrayList<byte>). Я предпочел лист, из-за присутствия в нем основных методов работы с ним, а так же из-за духа ООП. К тому же, есть потокобезопасные листы.

Comment: PPPS (^_^): Опять же, лучшим решением будет не использование ридеров и райтеров, а прямое использование стримов.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за столь подробное описание, кода конкретного не нужно, буду делать по 3ему пункту)

Comment: Это радует, что кода не нужно. Сейчас такая тенденция: "зачем модульное программирование, если есть блочное копирование?". Вырождаются программисты... Печалит.

Comment: немного про свою боль. На одном проекте ждали первого байта, а когда тот успешно приходил, считывали все из буфера. До сих пор не понимаю как оно работало постоянно не падая. При том, что в сообщении есть 4 байта с указанием длинны сообщения

Comment: @Евгений Карпов Вот тут "Сетевые пакеты ни как не обозначают свою длину" - можно понять двояко. Как таковых пакетов для пользователя не существует, есть только посл. байт. Пакеты есть на уровне протокола и сетевого взаимодействия, и там у них длина конечно же  есть.

Answer (score 2):

Нужен протокол, собственно софтверная его часть, скажем в самом примитивном исполнении так:

```
public class MyProtocol {
  final String beginner="$BEGIN$";
  String data;
  final String terminator="$END$"
}
```

Тогда вы точно будете знать где начало и где конец ваших данных и не будете зависеть от капризов сокетов.

Comment: Об этом велосипеде я и писал в своем ответе под пунктом 2. Использовать треминаторы далеко не всегда оправдано, особенно терминаторы пакета... Не спорю, что таким образом можно отследить начало следующего пакета при частичной утере байтов, но возможны ложные срабатывания, если в пакете передаётся строка: она может содержать символы окончания пакета.

Я бы, пожалуй, если бы гипотетически нельзя было реализовать пункт третий, воспользовался бы фиксированной длиной пакета с ещё парой идей.

Comment: Ну можно терминатор сделать более умным и добавить в него нечто вроде контроля четности. У меня сделано все таким образом - сбои в связи фиксируются на раз и отслеживается есть ли повтор терминатора в передаче

Comment: @Евгений Карпов, вот про *частичную утрю байтов*, если можно, поподробнее.

Я то всю жизнь считал, что от этой напасти TCP (да и UDP тоже (пропасть тут может пакет (дейтаграмма) целиком)) избавлен. Вот искажение байт, хотя и крайне маловероятно, т.к. протокол считает контрольные суммы и обеспечивает повторную передачу испорченных пакетов, но возможно.

Правда не знаю, насколько часто можно обнаружить это примитивным контролем четности  в прикладных данных.

@Barmaley, а Вы, отслеживая терминаторы, видимо отлавливаете сбои в логике прикладного протокола?

Comment: @avp протокол проложен поверх смсок. Смски мультипартные, некоторые части могут теряться или может нарушаться очередность приема - оттуда и такие мероприятия.

Comment: @avp, Как уже писалось выше - в TCP нет пакетов как таковых. Передача осуществляется потоком данных. Из этого потока могут выпасть или исказиться некоторое количество байт (например, при воздушной передаче из-за сильных помех). Если программист протокола не предусмотрит контроль целостности - то быть беде.

Но, сказать по правде, я с таким ещё не сталкивался, только с утерей целого пакета...

Comment: @Евгений Карпов, думаю Вы сталкивались с утерей *логического пакета Вашего прикладного протокола*, т.е. с ошибкой прикладных программ (клиента-сервера).

Поверьте, в потоке байт TCP этого не быает. Если канал **очень** плохой, то **ничего** передаваться не будет и через некоторое время соединение закроется.

Answer (score 0):

Я сталкивался с взаимодействием сервер-клиент по сокету. Там была четко разработана структура пакета, он имел строго определенный размер и разметку, первые 12 символов отвечали за назначение пакета(##-так пакет начинался, далее шла служебная информация о id пользователя и тп), далее шла информация которая предназначалась пользователю, а на конце последние два значения отвечали за целостность строки (CRC, если строка не проходила проверку, запрос повторялся 3 раза)

Я к тому что нужно объединить несколько методов контроля данных

1. Фиксировать размер пакета. Встречал несколько раз в чужом коде. Наличествует ещё и свой буфер, в который до нужного заполнения сливают данные буфера сокета, и читают нужными порциями. Стоит ли говорить, что вещь ужасно хардкодная?
2. В пакете означают его конец, к примеру каким-нибудь сочетанием 00-FF-00-FF. Встречал 2 раза. Велосипедизм. Возможны ложные срабатывания детектора конца пакета. - Только тут надо обозначить не конец, а начало строки.

Comment: ты это про что?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не внимательно прочитал тело ответа.

Но зачем объединять велосипед с бредом? Возьмите любой продукт, который давно присутствует на рынке, и пользуется спросом - в 95% случаев, полагаю, там будет решение из третьего пункта.

Для примера могу сослаться на немалоизвестный эмулятор сервера Lineage - L2J (точнее на пакетную архитектуру самой игры): 2 байта размера, с помощью которых читается весь пакет, дальее 2 байта - идентификатор пакета. Далее либо субидентификатор, либо набор данных.

Такое решение работает без сбоев уже более 8 лет.

Comment: Копировать запрещено? Если ты прочитаешь мой ответ полностью, а не будешь любоваться только своим текстом, то ты поймешь, что его я привел как вариант какие методы есть. На авторство последних двух абзацев я не претендовал. lol

Велосипед был изобретен не мной, а используется в протоколе обмена сообщениями в программном комплексе такса(таксишная программа)

Comment: Я извинился. Просто как-то...ммм.. необычно видеть полные цитаты, логичнее было бы "я к тому, что нужно объединить несколько методов контроля данных: 1 и 3 из прошлого ответа". Да и двоеточие не надолкнуло меня на мысль о перечислении (точнее, его отсутствие).

Comment: >>Велосипед был изобретен не мной, а используется

А зачем заведомо велосипедный код предлагать, да ещё и комбинировать с бредом? К тому же, если вы поддерживаете этот код - почему не переписать его полностью во вменяемое состояние? Поддержку CRC можно реализовать и для третьего варианта.

Comment: К тому же, не совсем логически понимаю, какой смысл делать пакет фиксированного размера, а затем означать его конец (добавлять терминационные данные)?

Comment: Изобретение по новой велосипеда - эта не всегда беда. С той структурой пакета было работать одно удовольствие. Я писал клиента для сервера который общался такими велосипедными пакетами и структура пакета меня не разу не подвела, она съедала минимум денег(была очень короткой), и всегда я точно знал, что пакет целый(контроль целостности пакета). Точная структура пакета, ограниченная количеством байт - в сумме дало очень стойкую и практичную связь между сервером и клиентом. простую, но мощную реализацию общения сервер/клиент - это как автомат Калашникова. Минусов у такой системы практически нет 

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то, маленькие последовательные сообщения действительно склеиваются в один TCP пакет, благодаря алгоритму Nagle. Так экономится трафик, опуская заголовок пакета  40 байт (20 байт TCP + 20 байт IPv4) для каждого сообщения. Алгоритм можно отключить задав `Socket.NoDelay=true;` а "мелкие" сообщения упаковать в массив, сериализировать его и отравлять в таком виде.